# Rebus puting weird characters at HEADER dictionary JSON written at MSMQ Extension Property

Tags: c#, encoding, msmq, rebus

I have an aplication which writes a message using Publish/Subscriber pattern with Rebus implementation.
At some point, without any code changes, Rebus started writing the MSMQ Extension binary content with some weird characters after JSON content, here follows an example of one taken message with the issue:

> {"rbs2-intent":"pub","rbs2-msg-id":"ac543d60-e28c-49bb-8783-b5c6574a90ea","rbs2-return-address":"myqueuename@SERVERNAME","rbs2-senttime":"2018-04-26T00:20:48.0453055-03:00","rbs2-corr-id":"ac543d60-e28c-49bb-8783-b5c6574a90ea","rbs2-corr-seq":"0","rbs2-msg-type":"ClassNamespace.BusinessClassName,
>   ClassNamespace","rbs2-content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","rbs2-content-encoding":"gzip"}?k?h?3??
>   ?   /??w

Here is the full error message I receive on my lof4net log file, written by Rebus when doing the message receive from MSMQ.

> 2018-05-03 10:33:49,516 WARN 
>   Rebus.Workers.ThreadPoolBased.ThreadPoolWorker - An error occurred
>   when attempting to receive the next message:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Could not
>   deserialize JSON text
>   '{"rbs2-intent":"pub","rbs2-msg-id":"ac543d60-e28c-49bb-8783-b5c6574a90ea","rbs2-return-address":"myqueuename@SERVERNAME","rbs2-senttime":"2018-04-26T00:20:48.0453055-03:00","rbs2-corr-id":"ac543d60-e28c-49bb-8783-b5c6574a90ea","rbs2-corr-seq":"0","rbs2-msg-type":"ClassNamespace.BusinessClassName,
>   ClassNamespace","rbs2-content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","rbs2-content-encoding":"gzip"}?k?h?3??
>   ?   /??w R?   ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException:
>   Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: .
>   Path '', line 1, position 432.    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Rebus.Serialization.HeaderSerializer.DeserializeFromString(String str)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Rebus.Serialization.HeaderSerializer.DeserializeFromString(String str)
>   at Rebus.Msmq.MsmqTransport.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Rebus.Workers.ThreadPoolBased.ThreadPoolWorker.d__17.MoveNext()

After some time digging into this problem, I managed do diassembly Rebus implemetation for MSMQ "MsmqTransport" class and I could see how Rebus is communication with MSMQ, also how is the Extension property being filled with Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes binary data.

What is not clear to me is how come a `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.Serialize(Dictionary<string,string>))` could result in that messed up array of bytes.

I'm considering that this implementation of Rebus MsmqTransport for MSMQ cannot be affected by my code, either by the object I'm sending to MSMQ, in which is going to be placed at Message Body, not Extension binary or by the way I'm configuring it.

As a workaround, in order to keep all solution running, I've implemented a service in which peeks the message from MSMQ, does a Encoding.UTF8.GetString from Exteions property bytes, analyse it, fix it in case of wierd characters and pull it back (the healthy JSON) at Extension property, then dequeue it from MSMQ and re enqueue it back to MSMQ, so the real process using Rebus (the Subscriber) will be able to receive it properly.

Is there a way I can figure it out how Rebus is messing up with the binary data written at Extension property of MSMQ message!?

Here is how I'm configuring Rebus at the Publisher implementation:

```
Bus = Configure.With(activator)
                       .Logging(l => l.Trace())
                       .Options(o =>
                                {
                                    o.SimpleRetryStrategy(Config.ErrorQueue, Config.MaxDeliveryAttempts == 0 ? 3 : Config.MaxDeliveryAttempts);
                                    if (Config.EnableCompression)
                                        o.EnableCompression();
                                })
                       .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq(Config.PublisherQueue))
                       .Subscriptions(s => s.Register(c => SubscriptionStorage))
                       .Start();
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds really weird!

As you have correctly figured out, the way Rebus populates the `Extension` property of the MSMQ `Message` does not leave that much room for weird bugs and funny behavior like what you're experiencing.

I once used Rebus at a customer's site though, and stuff was working fine for a long time – but suddenly, also without any code changes, weird stuff started to turn up in the `Extension` part of our MSMQ messages too, very similar to what you're seeing.

After much pondering and head-shaking, we found out that out customer had hired another company to help them with general performance monitoring and stuff, and one of their initiatives involved something that would use the `Extension` property of MSMQ messages, messing with Rebus' headers, thus breaking everything.

I don't know if it's "standard MSMQ practice", or why they would just start messing with our messages like that without even asking us if it would be a problem, but maybe it could be something similar in your case?

If not, I don't really have any clues.

Comment: mookid8000, thanks a lot for your anwser. I'll check it out, if our customer has something like that, some performance working on MSMQ. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for flooding this comments. I'd like also to share my workaround for this Issue.
In order to clean up the header for the MSMQ messages, I've implemented that windows service which does a peek for the next message, converts the binary Extensions and check it out the JSON for validation. In order to accomplish that, I used the JToken.Parse for JSON format validation.
Do you think you could internalize this test, in case of serialization fail of your Dictionary<string,string> for better troubleshooting? Thanks.

Comment: Hi again @mookid8000.
After a hard struggle with this issue, I got nothing. 
Our client server doens't get any third party software running under MSMQ, nothing is using MSMQ except our software and the only monitoring they use is PerformanceCounter.
I have read Rebus code many times, trying to figure it out how it's messing up with binary extension data, but no success at all. The only part I could consider an issue is the "IsUtf7" method, which is used to define what Encoding will be used to deserialize header dictionary. Do you think it might be something?

Comment: No – the `IsUtf7` method is not used anymore. It used to enable for Rebus to work in "legacy compatibility mode", but that feature was removed in Rebus 3 IIRC. I'm sorry, but as you can tell, the code doesn't really do anything out of the ordinary. If I were you, I would try and code a small test app that can send/receive lots of messages, to verify that the `Extension` property is actually not being messed with by anything.

Comment: Thanks @mookid8000.
That's so nice, I just did this app today.
I wrote a small WinForms app that starts up some configure qtd of threads and uses either MSMQ manually code or Rebus to send messages.
I've done some testing and sending over 200000 messages using up to 180 parallel threads, using both implementations, didn't messed up with the Extension property.
Right now I'm sure, at least running on my PC, that the issue is not about concurrency.